# Can the rollback of Spring declarative transaction be postponed

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions

**Question**:
Is there a way to allow Spring declarative transaction to postpone the rollback on exception ?

**Use case**:

- I have to process several entities together in a single transaction.
- The result of processing a single entity are a few new records in the DB and a few updates to existing ones.
- If processing of any of those entities results in an exception, the transaction needs to be rolled back. So, all entities must be processed successfully in order for transaction to be committed.
- **The twist**: I want to detect all the entities for which processing ends up with exception in one go. I do not want to run processing once, fail on entity No5, fix the issues on entity No5, and then run processing again only to be greeted by an exception on entity No7.

So, what I am trying to achieve is to gather all the errors on entities that are in a faulty state and notify someone to fix them. Due to this, I want the transaction that encapsulates all entities processing to carry on till the last entity and only then I want a rollback to happen.

What I tried so far:

**Using `propagation = NESTED` like this**:

```
@Transactional
void processAllEntities() {
    entities = fetchEntities();
    for (entity : entities) {
        processSingleEntity();
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = NESTED)
void processSingleEntity(entity) {
    do stuff;
}
```

Please note that methods above are in different `@Component` annotated classes and `processAllEntities()` is invoked from a third class.

This failed because `JpaDialect` does not support savepoints.

I tried to switch to `DataSourceTransactionManager` as suggested in the javadoc of `Propagation.NESTED` but then nothing is persisted since this transaction manager seems to be `JPA` unaware and my whole model is mapped with `JPA` annotations and I'm using `spring-data-jpa` for persistence.

Any ideas and feedback are welcome. Thanks.